# How to perform create and update in has_many :through association?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, associations, has-many-through

**Note**:

I put all of my source code for this app [here](https://github.com/zulhfreelancer/school).

---

I have this inside my **schema.rb** file:

```
create_table "courses", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.integer  "teacher_id"
    t.integer  "student_id"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.integer  "quantity"
  end

  create_table "students", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "name"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
  end

  create_table "teachers", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "name"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
  end
```

My teacher model:

```
class Teacher < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :courses
    has_many :students, :through => :courses
end
```

My student model:

```
class Student < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :courses
    has_many :teachers, :through => :courses
end
```

My course model:

```
class Course < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :teacher
    belongs_to :student
end
```

And I have empty `add_student` method inside my teachers_controller like this:

```
def add_student

end
```

The **add_student.html.erb** inside **views/teachers** folder:

```
hello from add_student!

<%= form_for(@course) do |f| %>
  <% if @course.errors.any? %>
    <div id="error_explanation">
      <h2><%= pluralize(@course.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this course from being saved:</h2>

      <ul>
      <% @course.errors.full_messages.each do |message| %>
        <li><%= message %></li>
      <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
  <% end %>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.select :student_id, Student.all.collect { |p| [ p.name, p.id ] } %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
      <%= f.number_field :quantity %>
  </div>
  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

What I'm trying to do inside this `add_student` is adding `students` and `quantity` accordingly.

But I get this error:

```
First argument in form cannot contain nil or be empty
```

Which refers to this line:

```
<%= form_for(@course) do |f| %>
```

**My questions**:

1. How to display all `students` name in a dropdown and give them `quantity` inside this `add_student` method?
2. How to make this also works using POST request (like an API) so that I can simply POST params like this:

`[{"student_id":1, "quantity":2},{"student_id":2, "quantity":3}]`

3. How to make the `update` method for this `add_student` using form and `PUT` request so that I can pass the same style of params like such?

`[{"student_id":1, "quantity":2},{"student_id":2, "quantity":3}]`

**Note #1**:

This is all my routes:

```
Prefix Verb   URI Pattern                         Controller#Action
        root GET    /                                   courses#index
     courses GET    /courses(.:format)                  courses#index
             POST   /courses(.:format)                  courses#create
  new_course GET    /courses/new(.:format)              courses#new
 edit_course GET    /courses/:id/edit(.:format)         courses#edit
      course GET    /courses/:id(.:format)              courses#show
             PATCH  /courses/:id(.:format)              courses#update
             PUT    /courses/:id(.:format)              courses#update
             DELETE /courses/:id(.:format)              courses#destroy
    students GET    /students(.:format)                 students#index
             POST   /students(.:format)                 students#create
 new_student GET    /students/new(.:format)             students#new
edit_student GET    /students/:id/edit(.:format)        students#edit
     student GET    /students/:id(.:format)             students#show
             PATCH  /students/:id(.:format)             students#update
             PUT    /students/:id(.:format)             students#update
             DELETE /students/:id(.:format)             students#destroy
    teachers GET    /teachers(.:format)                 teachers#index
             POST   /teachers(.:format)                 teachers#create
 new_teacher GET    /teachers/new(.:format)             teachers#new
edit_teacher GET    /teachers/:id/edit(.:format)        teachers#edit
     teacher GET    /teachers/:id(.:format)             teachers#show
             PATCH  /teachers/:id(.:format)             teachers#update
             PUT    /teachers/:id(.:format)             teachers#update
             DELETE /teachers/:id(.:format)             teachers#destroy
             GET    /teachers/:id/add_student(.:format) teachers#add_student
```

**Note #2**

I put all of my source code for this app [here](https://github.com/zulhfreelancer/school).

Comment: The error is due to you haven't initialized `@course` in `add_student` method

Comment: @Pavan I put `@course` inside the `add_student` method but still get the error. Can you look at my github repo and help me initizalize the `@course`?

Answer (score 0):

pleas do this in your teachers_controller

```
 def add_student
    @course = Course.new
 end
```

currently your method is empty and @course is nil

Comment: and in your form you also need hidden field to set teacher_id #<%= f.hidden_field :teacher_id, @teacher.id %> also in teachers controller add method add student to the before filter for set_teacher.

Comment: Ok. But when I try to assign a new student to a teacher, I get this: http://i.imgur.com/N5KTYXa.png. And when I check my data, `teacher_id` value is `null`. Any idea?

Comment: how are you assigning teacher_id to student. using hidden field or some other way. can you share.?

Comment: I put this `<%= f.hidden_field :teacher_id %>` inside my add_student.html.erb file like you said. Is that correct? Btw, I put all my source code at my Github repo here https://github.com/zulhfreelancer/school

Comment: #<%= f.hidden_field :teacher_id, teacher.id %>  please put teacher.id after :teacher_id.

Comment: check my first comment.. to the answer.. i put the @teacher.id in hidden field to be set as value.

Comment: Ok. I just updated my code. Now it says ```undefined local variable or method `teacher' for #<#<Class:0x007ff0be5c1dc0>:0x007ff0c0078e48>```. Any idea?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/83301/discussion-between-athar-and-zulhfreelancer).

Answer (score 0):

To make post or update request you need to pass url and method options to form_for tag. Follow followings step:-

1. Inside add_student method, initialize @course variable.
2. overwrite the from tag with options value as:-

   To create the record: <%= form_for(@course, url: courses_path, method: :post) do |f| %>

   To update the record: <%= form_for(@course, url: course_path(@course), method: :put) do |f| %>

Thanks

Comment: I get this - http://i.imgur.com/54AqX2e.png. Seems like it can't capture the teacher id right?

Comment: You need to include hidden field teacher_id as <%= f.hidden_field :teacher_id, value: params[:id] %>